# Gradle package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm not exists

Tags: java, gradle

jdk 1.8.0_201
gradle 6.9.2

```
compileJava{
    options.compilerArgs += '-XDignore.symbol.file'
    options.fork = true
}
or
tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
    configure(options){
        options.compilerArgs += "-XDignore.symbol.file"
        //options.compilerArgs.add("-XDignore.symbol.file")
        options.fork = true
        options.verbose = true
    }

dependencies {
    implementation files("${System.properties['java.home']}/lib/rt.jar")
    implementation files("${System.properties['java.home']}/lib/jce.jar")
    implementation files("${System.properties['java.home']}/lib/jsse.jar")
}
```

```
public class HelloDump implements Opcodes {
    public static byte[] dump(){
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        cw.visit(V1_8, ACC_PUBLIC|ACC_SUPER, "nx.example.asm", null, "java/lang/Object",null);
        ......
        cw.visitEnd();

        return cw.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
but run main method get error:package jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm not exists

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  I have removed the incorrect tag "assembly" from your post.  When you type a tag a description appears which shows what it is for, so please take care when adding tags in future. "assembly" is for assembly language, not web assemblies of webby things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
configure(options){
    options.compilerArgs.add("-XDignore.symbol.file=true")
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
    options.encoding = 'utf-8'
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).